# Как сделать в фильтре - “показать по”

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На картинке в блоке есть часть - "показать по". Не знаю, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии менялось количество отображаемых объектов. Сайт на WP с плаг[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ином woocommerce

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать в фильтре - "показать по"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185327/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be)

Answer (score 0):

Установил плагин - Products per Page for WooCommerce, е совсем то, что нужно, но вполне ничего. В коде в папке плагина есть файл - class-alg-wc-products-per-page-core.php. В нем есть строка - apply_filters( 'alg_wc_products_per_page_select_options', и тут идут сколько будет показываться, можно вставить свои значения. Вроде все работает. О